# How to fetch more api data

Tags: angular, typescript

I've followed this tutorial https://developer.telerik.com/content-types/tutorials/step-step-guide-building-master-detail-user-interfaces-angular/

which uses the https://pokeapi.co/

here is the github for the code https://github.com/tjvantoll/angular-master-detail

I don't know how to add more data to the details view. Can someone show me how I would fetch more data? Just something simple such as weight and height or the abilities.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at [ask] and consider updating your question. Questions that don't show any attempt or effort to solve the problem aren't generally well received by the community. SO isn't a coding service and shouldn't be treated as such. :)

Comment: I'm more or less just curious.. I'm a complete beginner and don't know where to start. Just looking for a point in the right direction. But thanks

Comment: I understand, if you're a complete beginner to the Angular world a great place to begin is with the official Angular Tour of Heros tutorial. Complete the tutorial and you will be armed with the knowledge you need to solve this problem. https://angular.io/tutorial Good luck and happy coding.

Comment: Thank you, I will do that tutorial right now lol.